# How to select parameters for nn.Linear layer while training a CNN?

Tags: python-3.x, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to train a CNN to classify images from the `Fashion-MNIST` data using `Conv2d`, `Maxpool` and `Linear` layers. I came across a code as mentioned below with `in_features = 12*4*4` in `nn.Linear` layer.

Can I please get help on how to select an `in_features` parameter for nn.Linear layer?

```
class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Network, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=6, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=6, out_channels=12, kernel_size=5)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=12*4*4, out_features=120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=120, out_features=60)
        self.out = nn.Linear(in_features=60, out_features=10)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each example in the `Fashion-MNIST` dataset is a `28 x 28` grayscale image.

1. Input is `28 x 28`
2. We do a `5 x 5` convolution without padding(since `default padding=0`) and `stride=1(by default)`, so we lose `2` pixels at each side, we drop down to `24 x 24`, i.e.,(28-5)/1 + 1
3. We then perform maxpooling operation with receptive field of `2 x 2`, we cut each dimension by half, down to `12 x 12`
4. We again do another `5 x 5` convolution without `padding` and `stride=1`, we drop down to `8 x 8`, i.e.,(12-5)/1 + 1
5. Then, we perform another maxpooling operation, we drop down to `4 x 4`

That's why, `self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=12*4*4, out_features=120)`. It's basically, `n_features_conv * height * width`, where height and width are `4` respectively and `n_features_conv`  is same as `out_channels` of the `conv2D` layer lying just above it.

Note if you change the size of input image, then you will have to perform the above calculations and adjust the first `Linear` layer accordingly.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: oh okay..thank you got it...so how is the out_features in the 1st layer of Linear calculated and also is there a specific way to select the out_channels in Conv2d layers?

Comment: When I apply the above calculation for facial_keypoint detection project by Udacity, I am not getting the correct values as mentioned. After the final maxpooling operation I am getting 49x49 which seems to be incorrect when i calculate in_features for 1st Linear layer. Input size is 224x224. Find the code below:

Comment: self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 5) self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 5)self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 5) self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2) self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 5) self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d(256, 512, 5) #self.conv6 = nn.Conv2d(512, 1024, 5) self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2) #self.fcl1 = nn.Linear(25600, 2048) self.fcl1 = nn.Linear(4608, 2048) self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(p=0.1) self.fcl2 = nn.Linear(2048, 1024) self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(p=0.2) self.fcl3 = nn.Linear(1024, 136)

Comment: @user11619814, sorry but I forget to clarify one thing. You don't apply above steps just by looking at __init__(). You follow these as per the forward(). There must be some method with name forward in your above class Network. __init__() just initializes the various layers but it's inside forward() where real connection is made between different initialized layers.

Comment: I applied my above steps on a tutorial at https://blog.algorithmia.com/convolutional-neural-nets-in-pytorch/ to check if it's right or not. I am getting the result as expected. Input size(3, 32, 32) -> Conv2d(3, 18, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1) -> (32-3+2)/1 + 1 -> (32,32) -> MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0) -> (32-2)/2 + 1 -> (16,16) -> in_features=(18*16*16) which is meaningful as per the blog.

Comment: @user11619814, so just by seeing layers details inside __init__ layers, I can't tell you the input to the first Linear Layers. You have to check the forward() to apply above steps.

Comment: check this out: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/40906/determining-size-of-fc-layer-after-conv-layer-in-pytorch. It helps you decide input of the Linear Layer.

Comment: out_features in the 1st layer of Linear is selected arbitrarily such that the resulting network performs well.

Comment: There is also an another good resource where you can read about these things in details: https://www.deeplearningwizard.com/deep_learning/practical_pytorch/pytorch_convolutional_neuralnetwork/

Comment: Thank you for the links...it helped a lot... as you told these calculations are based on layers in forward method.Is there a link/tutorial where I can see how to make connection with the layers in forward method? and one last question: if we use the dropout layer(as in the code in my previous post), does this dropout layer value effect the calculation for layer parameters? –

Comment: check this code: self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(512, 256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.2),
            nn.Linear(256, 1)
        )

Comment: You can see here `in_channels` of second `Linear` layer is still the same as `out_channels` of layer before it. dropout layer randomly disables/deactivates some portion of neuron in hidden layer.

Comment: Go through this Cross Validated answers to know when and where to use dropout layer. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240305/where-should-i-place-dropout-layers-in-a-neural-network

Comment: oh okay...got it....thank you so much for your help...really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If a CNN has fc layers in the end, first you've to decide on the input size. Next you have three options:

1. Do the math yourself. Calculate how tensor sizes change as they go through different conv, pooling layers.
2. Just input a random tensor of the size you fixed through the initial layers. Then see the size of the output (`tensor.size()`). In the example you gave it would be (`torch.Size([12, 4, 4])`).
3. Use something like [tsalib](https://github.com/ofnote/tsalib) to handle resizing behind the scenes.

I personally prefer method 2 because it's fast, accurate and doesn't need any 3rd party libraries.